# How can i add an extra Fee compatible with PayPal?

Tags: magento-1.9, invoice, paypal, extrafee

I added a Module that adds an `extra Fee (via Discount)` when I order products for less than 50€. That module works for `invoice payment`. 
When i want to pay via `PayPal`, I get an error like **"there is a mistake"**...

How can archive that? My idea was to create an observer that modifies the `Paypal-Information...` But how exactly i can make that?

I tried the following code:

```
public function paypalPrepareLineItems($observer)
    {
        /* @var $cart Mage_Paypal_Model_Cart */
        $cart = $observer->getEvent()->getPaypalCart();
        $address = $cart->getSalesEntity()->getIsVirtual() ?
            $cart->getSalesEntity()->getBillingAddress() : $cart->getSalesEntity()->getShippingAddress();
        $feeAmount = $address->getExtraFeeRuleAmount();
        $cart->updateTotal(Mage_Paypal_Model_Cart::TOTAL_DISCOUNT, $feeAmount);
    }
```

Thank you, Chris